# Django nested serializer for multiple models, with chained foreignKeys

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Let's use these 3 simple models for example. A city can have multiple shops, and a shop can have multiple products

**models.py**

```
class City(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='related_city', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    shop=models.ForeignKey(Shop, related_name='related_shop', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields=['id','name']

class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    related_shop = CitySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields=['id','name','related_city']

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    related_shop = ShopSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields=['id','name','related_shop']
```

In views.py, in the get_queryset(), I am using .select_related().all() to fetch the foreign objects.
ProductSerializer will give me all products, and will fetch the foreignKey shops, and I will also get the names of the shops where this product is found.

ShopSerializer, in a similar way, will give me all shops names, and all the cities where this shop can be found.

But how can I make a serializer, that will retrieve from all 3 tables at once?
The fields I want are:
fields=['product_name','shop_name', 'city_name']

I know that, that list I will get will have repetitions, and can be considered 1NF or 2NF, opposed to the model design I have as database 3NF. But that is the query that I want.

I was actually thinking of denormalizing my database, so I can easily achieve this.

My second question is, is it better to denormalize it to 1NF, and have repetitions, so that I reduce the CPU intensive inner joins on 'id' between these 3 tables? I researched a lot about this, and usually the lazy answer is: Try both variants, benchmark, and decide yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be different approaches available for your question. Fetching related objects from the database at once does not depend on the serializer itself actually. That's done in your view layer where you can append `select_related('shop__city')` to your queryset. By appending this you will have both `shop` and the `shop.city` values preloaded on `Product`objects in a single query.

A simple way of serializing those fields is to set `source` in the serializer fields like below:

```py
class ProductSerializerV2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shop_name = serializers.CharField(source='shop.name')
    city_name = serializers.CharField(source='shop.city.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'shop_name', 'city_name']
```

#### Conclusion

According to the descriptions above, the below snippet will only have a single query to the database

```py
p = Product.objects.select_related('shop__city').last()
print(ProductSerializerV2(p).data)  
# {'name': 'product-z', 'shop_name': 'shop-z', 'city_name': 'z'} as a sample output
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that code works! I am curious if you know from experience, if you can help with the second question as well - is it more efficient to denormalize the database to 1NF or 2NF, or keep it as it is right now in 3NF, and make these 2 inner joins between these 3 tables? The scenario is, ecommerce website, showing products page, and with each I want to immediately show the shop & city where that product is available. Will I have the bottleneck in the CPU at the inner joins, or at transferring the bigger table with all those repetitive fields from the 1NF ?

Comment: IMHO you may want to avoid denormalizing until you face performance issues. Again the correct answer depends on variables like the database you use and the scale of the data you are working with. I think profiling requests via some tools like `django-silk` will help you decide whether you need denormalizing tables or accepting the join overhead.

Answer (score 1):

use source like this:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shop_name = serializers.CharField(source='shop.name')
    city_name = serializers.CharField(source='shop.city.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'shop_name', 'city_name']
```

for second question. you may act like this:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    city=models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='product_city', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shop=models.ForeignKey(Shop, related_name='product_shop', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

by using this you can access to city and shop for each product easily in template or whatever your gonna use for forntend and there is less pressure on database to achieving product's shop and city

Comment: thanks a lot, that code works! I am curious if you know from experience, if you can help with the second question as well - is it more efficient to denormalize the database to 1NF or 2NF, or keep it as it is right now in 3NF, and make these 2 inner joins between these 3 tables? The scenario is, ecommerce website, showing products page, and with each I want to immediately show the shop & city where that product is available. Will I have the bottleneck in the CPU at the inner joins, or at transferring the bigger table with all those repetitive fields from the 1NF ?

Comment: You're right, clever way of avoiding one join. Thank you!